# Can i create custom content type without define .yml file in module?

Tags: 8

Sorry for my bad english grammar.
I write a module, allows the user to upload a file that contain list of content types infomation. Then my module will auto create content type for user.
But i don't know how to create content type without hard define many .yml file.

Answer (score 0):

If your content type is fairly straight forward (i.e. using only Drupal's fields), you can create the content type within the `http://localhost/admin/structure/types/add` link and once you have it built the way you want it you can export it via: `http://localhost/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`.

It will even give you the name of yaml file to boot!

If that avenue is not sufficient then you can follow: [This tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8) about building custom drupal content entities; it is lengthy in nature, which is why I will elide the details.

And if you're going to use that tutorial, then I would suggest using [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/) to generate the boilerplate code for you.  It makes things quite simple.  Drupal Console, among other things, manages the generation of content entity boilerplate code.  It is quite helpful.

Comment: tks u! 
I know that way to create content type.
But i has found programmatically to create by use $new_bundle = NodeType::create() and $new_bundle->save().
btw, tks for your anwser!.